# Compiz Clampdown?

Tags: compiz

I'm using Gnome.

I've discovered suddenly that I can't resize most windows. I hover over an edge or the lower right corner and the drag bar appears, but I'm not able to engage it. I tried turning off a lot of things I wasn't using in Compiz (which turned on ages ago, so why that would work I can't say) and now I can't even move windows around. The cursor behaves the way I'd expect but clicking and holding doesn't allow any movement.

It is obviously a little exasperating, and I'm wondering how to go about troubleshooting this.

Update: Compiz is *definitely* the issue. If I do `metacity --replace` I get a functional, no frills, [X Window Manager](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/X_window_manager). If I try to restore Compiz (`compiz --replace`) the problems come right back with it.

Comment: Can you click and drag in other places? (e.g. selecting text?)

Comment: @Nicholas Knight ... Yup. The only issue seems to be moving and resizing windows.

Answer (score 2):

Restoring Compiz defaults in CompizConfig Settings Manager did the trick (it is in the preferences tab)

That doesn't explain how everything got stuck in the first place, but it did get it unstuck. The other thing that worked was `metacity --replace` though that left me with ... metacity.

Answer (score -1):

Try to reset the compiz settings via terminal and restart X:

```
gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compiz
```

Comment: Does that do both or will that reset my compiz settings w/out restarting X?

Comment: This will reset only compiz settings, then you will need to restart X or simply reboot.

Comment: But you can't help point me towards a command line tool to restart X?

Comment: sudo killall gnome-session

Comment: Killing your whole gnome session is a lot more drastic than just restarting x.

Comment: If you don't like this way, you can use pkill X or restart gdm, or even enable ctrl+alt+backspace combination in gnome-keyboard-properties, but do you really think you gnome session will be ok while X restarting?

Comment: if you're interested in improving your answer, I suggest offering instructions for both proposed steps; and note for newbie users that you're suggesting that they force and end to their whole session (effectively logging them out).

Comment: My answer is far from ideal, but there is no harm in it for newbie users. All other comments are specific answers on your specific questions...

Comment: Either way, didn't work.

Comment: What about compiz resize window plugin in "ccsm", is it on? I've turn it off and get the same situation as yours.